# Could not launch environment: Application version is unusable and cannot be used with an environment

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I am following this tutorial https://prakhar.me/docker-curriculum/ and I am trying to create and EBS component.

For `Application version` I am uploading a file called `Dockerrun.aws.json` with the following content:

```
{
  "AWSEBDockerrunVersion": "1",
  "Image": {
    "Name": "myDockerHubId/catnip",
    "Update": "true"
  },
  "Ports": [
    {
      "ContainerPort": "5000"
    }
  ],
  "Logging": "/var/log/nginx"
}
```

However, I am getting this problem:

```
Error
Could not launch environment: Application version is unusable and cannot be used with an environment
```

Any idea why the configuration file is not good?

Answer (score -1):

I'm pretty sure this image

```
myDockerHubId/catnip
```

Does not exist on dockerhub.

Make sure You try to use an existent docker image from the dockerhub.

Comment: myDockerHubId stands for my DockerHub ID. Of course it doesn't exist